# Debugging Angular project

Tags: angular

Coming from an asp.net webforms/mvc/visual studio background.

I have created a new angular project (visual studio code) using cli. Made some changes to app.component.ts (but that's not important). 
Rendered page is absolutely empty.

I would like to know how to debug and know what is wrong?

Terminal shows

webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-02-26T01:29:02.482Z - Hash: 8bdb62ab120b22cea391 - Time: 1415ms
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 34.9 kB [initial] [rendered]

Html rendered is absolutely blank.

I was hoping the terminal would point to the problem but apparently it doesn't.
Also, chrome's developer tool console shows no error.

What are the first few things to check?

Comment: I would suggest checking this: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to debug in Angular

**1)    You can debug typescript files by using Sources in a Chrome browser.**

Steps: a) Open tsconfig.json file

b) Change SourceMap flag to true.

c) Open sources and put break point in .ts file in **Chrome developer** window.

**2)Debugger for Chrome**

Install Debugger extension for Chrome in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.